# Trying to get property of non-object php error

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call to a member function on a non-object - works localhost but not online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625941/call-to-a-member-function-on-a-non-object-works-localhost-but-not-online)

don't know how to solve this problem, it's basic but can't find a solution.
I use two files: connect.php and user.php.

in connect.php is a Connect class:

```
class Connect{
var $logged;
function login($username, $password){
    ..more code..
    if($pass==$password){
        $this->logged=true;     // db connection is fine, this works
                                // checked it with echo $this->logged;
    }
}
}
```

and when i call it from another file, user.php like this:

```
$user=new Connect;
$user->login();
echo $user->logged;      // ERROR  Trying to get property of non-object
```

Why is this code not working, but it works offline (locally)???

Comment: Your class definition is missing a `}`. Please don't post non-working code examples.

Comment: i know it's a duplicate post and i'm really sorry, i wish I didn't have this problem at all but i really need help.

Comment: @phpEnthusiast: Please don't duplicate questions only because your first question did not get the answer you would have loved to see (if any at all). Better think why users are not able to answer your question.

Comment: Note, also, when you try to print a `false` value, it will print nothing. Use `var_dump()` to see details about what the variable/value represents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems:

1. When you call `$user->login`, PHP is assuming you're accessing an object property, not the function; you need `$user->login()` (note the `()`), which will call the method.
2. Your example is missing a `}`.

**Demo:**

```
<?php

class Connect{
    var $logged;
    function login($username, $password){
        $pass = 'test';
        if($pass == $password){
            $this->logged = true;
        }
    }
}

$user = new Connect;
$user->login('test','test');
print_r($user);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/AVw0k9sY

**Outputs:**

```
Connect Object
(
    [logged] => 1
)
```

`1` is what `true` prints.

Comment: The problem is I don't get [logged]=>1 - instead of that i get error message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Not from the code above.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're talking about your actual code (as found in the other question). When you get that error, it's because the object creation didn't work (either the file wasn't created, the variable creation was incorrect or didn't occur before the accessing code, or some other problem). Change `include_once` to `require_once` and make sure error reporting is turned on. I'm guessing it's related to the `Connect.php` not being in the current directory.

Comment: ok, step by step: login() method in connect.php is called and does what it does. One of the results is that attribute `var $logged` should be true. When i check it internally in the login() method it is true. When i try the same thing from the external file (user.php) using this line: `var_dump($user->logged)` it gives NULL !? I really don't know where I should look for an answer

Comment: I don't know what you mean by external file; is it included AFTER the global `$user` variable is created? Or does it call and create a (local-to-the-user.php-script) `$user` variable of `Connect` type with the login?

Comment: what i meant by external is user.php file, which has this line on the top: `include_one('connect.php')`, or `require_once('connect.php');` This connection works until i want to echo `$user->logged` from user.php file, or call some other methods

Comment: And you create the `$user` object in `user.php` before `var_dump($user);`?

Comment: is there a reason why i don't get this error message locally, but get in when I try this code online?

Comment: The error/`NULL` value you're getting [indicates](http://codepad.org/qMWhIiZN) that `$user` is not an object; it's `NULL`, not declared, or `new` somehow didn't return an object. The logic you're using, you'll need to find out why. I can't tell you exactly why, you'll need to look at your code that's on your server to determine that. If you have the **identical** files in an **identical** file/folder structure, and it doesn't work on your server, you'll need to look at other details (database connection information) and eliminate/`/**/` everything but the basics for the object, and work back.

Comment: definitely is something wrong but cannot figure out what. It turned out that i get error for each attribute i create in the class Connect. Another thing, although calling and using login() method works fine, i get errors when calling other methods!? One of the method is `get_session($title)` which retrieves $_SESSION variables, and which I cannot use anymore, reason unknown. The whole application worked fine on localhost, and after setting it up online it stopped. All attributes and methods in other classes work fine. I need to have a deeper look

Comment: The problem you're having is impossible to specifically diagnose without reviewing everything on the server. So you really need to just roll up your sleeves and dig into it. When I have these kinds of problems with ad hoc code I've created, I comment out everything (starting at a high level) until the error goes away, and then slowly (using `exit()`s) try to zero in on the real problem, block by block, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

To access a class property from outside the class, you need to declare it as 'public':

```
class Connect{
public $logged;
```

Comment: Which deprecated `var` would do, see http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/language.oop.htm (just saying, it's better to write `public`)

Comment: This is what `var` does. It is legacy, but it is not wrong to do it with `var`.

Comment: also, i know that this code "should" work, because it does locally but don't know why i'm getting errors when i try to run it online